# custom global planner with multiple cpp and h files

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have created a custom planner following this tutorial:

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS

I created the files:

GA_global_planner.cpp and GA_global_planner.h

Also, I needed other utility classes:

Path.cpp, Path.h, Map.cpp, Map.h, GenericPathPlanner.cpp, GenericPathPlanner.h , OccupancyGridMap.cpp, OccupancyGridMap.h , all are necessary for the planning.

This is part of **GA_global_planner.h**,

```
#include "GenericPathPlanner.h"
#include "OccupancyGridMap.h"
#include "Map.h"
#include "Path.h"
class GAGlobalPlannerROS : public nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner, public GenericPathPlanner
```

**NOTE:** that the class GAGlobalPlannerROS inherits both BaseGlobalPlanner and GenericPathPlanner

**NOTE:** that the class OccupancyGridMap inherits public from class Map

I can successfully compile and build the package of this planner.

However, when I try to use the planner with move_base got error:

```
[FATAL] [1623866783.746869597, 0.412000000]: Failed to create the GA_planner/GAGlobalPlannerROS planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: Failed to load library /home/evadro/Desktop/Eman/ros_workspace/devel/lib//libGA_planner_lib.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/evadro/Desktop/Eman/ros_workspace/devel/lib//libGA_planner_lib.so: undefined symbol: _ZN18GenericPathPlanner8findPathEP16OccupancyGridMapP4Path)
[move_base-12] process has died [pid 17199, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/move_base/move_base __name:=move_base __log:=/home/evadro/.ros/log/8a34ae68-cecd-11eb-b87b-9e3f7c65cb79/move_base-12.log].
log file: /home/evadro/.ros/log/8a34ae68-cecd-11eb-b87b-9e3f7c65cb79/move_base-12*.log
```

When I rewrite the implementation without Path.cpp, Path.h, Map.cpp, Map.h, GenericPathPlanner.cpp, GenericPathPlanner.h , OccupancyGridMap.cpp, OccupancyGridMap.h, every thing works fine and I can use my planner in ROS.

However, I need to implement another custom planner, but I have to use Path.cpp, Path.h, Map.cpp, Map.h, GenericPathPlanner.cpp, GenericPathPlanner.h , OccupancyGridMap.cpp, OccupancyGridMap.h because the implementation will be very complicated without them.

How can I solve this problem ( using multiple cpp files with the custom planner)?

Many thanks

UPDATE:

**at the beginning of  the source GA_global_planner.cpp**

```
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(GA_planner::GAGlobalPlannerROS, nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner)
```

**at the beginning of GenericPathPlanner.cpp**

```
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(GenericPathPlanner, nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner)
```

**at the beginning of OccupancyGridMap.cpp**

```
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(OccupancyGridMap, nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner)
```

**at the beginning of Map.cpp**

```
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(Map, nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner)
```

**at the beginning of Path.cpp**

```
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(Path, nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner)
```

** The launch file **

```
<launch>
    <arg name="use_rosbot" default="false"/>
    <arg name="use_gazebo" default="true"/>
    <param if="$(arg use_gazebo)" name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
<!-- Bring the ROSbot model and show it in Gazebo and in Rviz  -->
    <include file="$(find rosbot_description)/launch/rosbot_rviz.launch"/>
<!-- Map server -->
    <arg name="map_file" default="$(find rosbot_navigation)/maps/willowgarage-refined.yaml"/>
    <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />
<!--- tf -->
    <node unless="$(arg use_rosbot)" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_odom_tf" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom 100" />  
    <node if="$(arg use_rosbot)" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" args="0 0 0 3.14 0 0 base_link laser 100" />
   
    <node pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" name="joint_state_publisher">
    <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="30.0" />
    </node>
<!--- Localization: Run AMCL -->
  <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
        <remap from="scan" to="/scan"/>
        <rosparam file="$(find rosbot_navigation)/config/amcl.yaml" command="load" />
      
    </node>
<!-- Move base -->
    <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" name="move_base" output="screen">
        <!-- <param name="base_global_planner" value="navfn/NavfnROS"/> -->
        <param name="base_global_planner" value="GA_planner/GAGlobalPlannerROS"/> 
        <param name="base_local_planner" value="teb_local_planner/TebLocalPlannerROS" /> 
        <param name="controller_frequency" value="30.0"/> <!-- default is 20.0 -->
        <rosparam file="$(find rosbot_navigation)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="$(find rosbot_navigation)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="$(find rosbot_navigation)/config/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <rosparam file="$(find rosbot_navigation)/config/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <rosparam file="$(find rosbot_navigation)/config/teb_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(GA_planner)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  nav_core
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES GA_planner
   CATKIN_DEPENDS nav_core roscpp rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
 include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(GA_planner_lib src/GA_global_planner.cpp)
```

**package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>GA_planner</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The GA_planner package</description>

  <maintainer email="eman@todo.todo">eman</maintainer>
  
  <license>TODO</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>nav_core</build_depend>
  <build_depend>nav_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>costmap_2d</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pluginlib</build_depend>
  <build_depend>tf</build_depend>
  
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>nav_core</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>costmap_2d</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>geometry_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>pluginlib</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>tf</exec_depend>


  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->
        <nav_core plugin="${prefix}/GA_planner_plugin.xml"/>
  </export>
</package>
```

**GA_planner_plugin.xml**

```
 <library path="lib/libmetabolic_pathways_planner_lib">
  <class name="GA_planner/GAGlobalPlannerROS" 
    type="GA_planner::GAGlobalPlannerROS" 
    base_class_type="nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner">
  <class type="GenericPathPlanner">
  <class type="OccupancyGridMap">
  <class type="Map">
  <class type="Path">
    <description>This is GA global planner plugin.</description>
  </class>
</library>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380483/custom-global-planner-with-multiple-cpp-and-h-files/) by [Eman.m](https://answers.ros.org/users/42689/eman.m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2021-06-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-06-16**:
Did you add `PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS` to your source code?

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-06-16**:
Did you update your `CMakeLists.txt` with `add_library(global_planner_lib src/path_planner/global_planner/global_planner.cpp)` ?

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-06-16**:
Did you create the `global_planner_plugin.xml` file in your package?

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-06-16**:
Did you update your `package.xml` file?

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-06-16**:
Please upate the post with the `launch` file you are using.

**Comment by [Eman.m](https://answers.ros.org/users/42689/eman.m/) on 2021-06-16**:
Thank you. I have edited my question above and added more details

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-06-17**:
What happens when you try to [query the package system](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS#Querying_ROS_Package_System_For_Available_Plugins) (`rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nav_core`)?

**Comment by [Eman.m](https://answers.ros.org/users/42689/eman.m/) on 2021-06-18**:
I added PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS at the beginning of each class composes the library, as I edit above.

Also I edit the plugin.xml and add all cpp files composes the library (edit above).

After .lanuch, i got different error:

```
Failed to create the GA_planner/GAGlobalPlannerROS planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class GA_planner/GAGlobalPlannerROS with base class type nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner does not exist. Declared types are navfn/NavfnROS
```

this the output of rospack:

```
clear_costmap_recovery /opt/ros/kinetic/share/clear_costmap_recovery/ccr_plugin.xml
teb_local_planner /opt/ros/kinetic/share/teb_local_planner/teb_local_planner_plugin.xml
navfn /opt/ros/kinetic/share/navfn/bgp_plugin.xml
rotate_recovery /opt/ros/kinetic/share/rotate_recovery/rotate_plugin.xml
base_local_planner /opt/ros/kinetic/share/base_local_planner/blp_plugin.xml
```

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-06-18**:
Are you able to `build` your package? If yes, did you run `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` after the `build` step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solve it:

1. no need for PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS in each .cpp, add it only in the planner's .cpp
2. in cMakeLists.txt

   add_library(GA_planner_lib src/GA_global_planner_ros.cpp src/GenericPathPlanner.cpp src/Map.cpp src/OccupancyGridMap.cpp src/Path.cpp)

That is, add all .cpp needed by your planner

---

Originally posted by [Eman.m](https://answers.ros.org/users/42689/eman.m/) with karma: 65 on 2021-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1